# Language Switch To Default After Logout Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, cookies

I have application using Spring Boot and have language selector.
I have problem: After I logged in, I set the language into another language than default language (from english into french) then after I log out, the language is set back to default language (english).

What I want is the language didn't change to default language. Can you help me?

NB:
- I use default spring boot authentication method (public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)
- I use default spring boot internationalization method (using public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor)
- I have search on internet and it seem that the language is set on cookies and the cookies is destroyed after logged out. I need another approach (like another method to save the registry of language or else) so it won't depend on log in and log out

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem is my localResolver is using session which it would be destroyed when the user logged out.
Solution: change to CookieLocaleResolver